# Mock only one attribute of all instances of a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have these 3 modules:

```py
# config.py
class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_attribute = "some value"  # <-- I want to mock this attribute
        self.another_attribute = 123
```

```py
# some_module.py
from config import Config

def method_that_uses_config():
    print(Config().another_attribute)  # This should not be mocked
    return Config().some_attribute  # This should be mocked
```

```py
# test_some_module.py:
from unittest.mock import patch

from some_module import method_that_uses_config

class TestConfig:
    @patch("some_module.Config")
    def test_method_that_uses_config(self, mock_config):
        mock_config.return_value.some_attribute = "mocked value"
        assert method_that_uses_config() == "mocked value"
```

This works only in part. The Config class is now completely mocked, while I'd like to only mock one specific attribute and leave the remaining attributes untouched:

```py
Config().some_attribute
# 'mocked value'
Config().another_attribute
# <MagicMock name='Config().another_attribute' id='4329847393'>
```

I'd like `Config().another_attribute` to return its original value (`123`) instead.
I basically want the Config instance to behave as it would normally do, with the only exception of the mocked attribute.

I think this should be quite basic, but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Why  does `method_that_uses_config` constantly create one-off instances of `Config`? Why isn't there a single "read-only" instance that gets shared?

Comment: @chepner I think that even if it was only one instance I would have the same issue, since I'm not passing the instance as a parameter to the class. In any case, this is simplified code to show what I'd like to do when mocking.

Comment: If there was only one instance, you would use something like `patch.object` to replace only the attribute in question on that object.

Comment: Most problems with mocking boil down to bad design. Fix the design, and mocking becomes simpler or even unnecessary.

Comment: @chepner would you like to show how you'd do that in an answer? I tried to change the code and use `@patch.object(shared_config, "some_attribute")` but I get the error "AttributeError: <config.Config object at 0x106b84ca0> does not have the attribute 'some_attribute'"

Comment: @chepner Please disregard the previous comment: I had made a mistake and your solution actually works. I'd be happy to accept it as the answer if you write it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is premised on the change to use one shared instance of `Config`, rather than repeatedly calling `Config` to make a new copy. For simplicity, we'll just use the class `Config` itself as that instance, rather than instantiating it.

```
# config.py
class C:
    some_attribute = "some value"
    another_attribute = 123

# some_module.py
from config import Config

def method_that_uses_config():
    print(Config.another_attribute)
    return Config.some_attribute
```

For your test, you can use `unittest.mock.patch.object` to replace the value of just the attribute you want to change.

```
# test_some_module.py:
from unittest.mock import patch

from some_module import method_that_uses_config

class TestConfig:
    @patch.object(some_module.Config, 'some_attribute', "mocked value")
    def test_method_that_uses_config(self, mock_config):
        assert method_that_uses_config() == "mocked value"
```

Here's a quick demonstration of how `patch.object` works.

```
>>> Config = class('Config', (), dict(a=1, b=2))
>>> p = patch.object(Config, 'a', 5)
>>> Config.a, Config.b
(1, 2)
>>> p.start()
5
>>> Config.a, Config.b
(5, 2)
>>> p.stop()
False
>>> Config.a, Config.b
(1, 2)
```

The `start` and `stop` methods are basically wrappers around the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, allowing you to manually "simulate" a `with` statement using the same patch.